# Java resource leak in PreparedStatement

Tags: java, sqlite, memory-leaks, prepared-statement

I'm writing a code in Java which involves databases (SQLite), and I'm new at it, so I need help with this one.
My code looks like this:

```
Connection connection = null;
try {
    connection = SQLiteConnector.getConnection(database Name);
    PreparedStatement prepStat = connection.prepareStatement("some SQL stuff"); 
    ResultSet result= prepStat.executeQuery();
    // Use of result

    if (condition1){

        prepStat = connection.prepareStatement("some SQL stuff");
        result = prepStat.executeQuery();
        // Another use of result

        if (condition2){
            prepStat = connection.prepareStatement("some SQL stuff");
        }
        else{
            prepStat = connection.prepareStatement("some SQL stuff");
        }

        result = prepStat.executeQuery();
        // Use of result

        result.close();
        prepStat.close();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Exception management
}
finally{
    SQLiteConnector.closeConnection(connection);
}
```

And I get an exception saying: "Resource leak: 'stat' is not closed at this location" in the *else* block. How should I refactor it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Post the stacktrace and point to the line that is throwing it. Or is it a compile time error?

Comment: The resource leak message is only a warning - your code will still compile and run if you don't address the issue. Assuming that you meant `prepStat` and not `stat`, is the warning being shown on the line `prepStat.close();` or thereabouts? Also, which version of the JDK are you using?

Comment: You don't seem to `.close()` the "first" `prepStat`, do you?

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22096398/possible-resource-leak-when-reusing-preparedstatement, you have to close the preparedStatement before reusing it.

Comment: Also, if you use Java 7+, `PreparedStatement` implements `AutoCloseable` so you may want to use a try-with-resources block

Comment: There is no `stat` here. Do you mean you get a *warning message* from some *code checker* saying that *`prepStat`* is not closed at this location?

Answer (score 1):

PreparedStatements should always be explicitly closed in JDBC. The general pattern for using a PreparedStatement is:

- Create the statement.
- Set the parameters and execute it.
- Set different parameters and execute it.
- Set yet more parameters and execute it.
- Close the statement.

From Java 7 onwards the easiest way to ensure you always do this properly is to use the statement within a [**try with resources**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) block.

Answer (score 1):

Use separate variables, definitely try-with-resources.

```
    try (PreparedStatement prepStat =
            connection.prepareStatement("some SQL stuff");
            ResultSet result = prepStat.executeQuery()) {
        ...
        try (PreparedStatement prepStat2 =
                connection.prepareStatement(condition2 ? "some SQL stuff" : "some SQL stuff") {
            try (ResultSet result2 = prepStat.executeQuery();
                // Use of result2
            }
        }
    }
```

Then everything is nicely closed, even with an exception or a return statement.

Answer (score 0):

You have not closed the prepStat before reusing it. Also try to close the statement in the finally block rather than try as it might leave closeable statements unclosed.

```
if (condition1){

    prepStat = connection.prepareStatement("some SQL stuff");
    result = prepStat.executeQuery();
    // Another use of result

    prepStat.close(); //close the statement 

    if (condition2){
        prepStat = connection.prepareStatement("some SQL stuff");
    }
    else{
        prepStat = connection.prepareStatement("some SQL stuff");
    }

    result = prepStat.executeQuery();
    // Use of result

    result.close();
    prepStat.close();
}
```